# Dividers on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've searched both Apple's docs and online and could not find any reference on how to create separators like those in the picture below. There are blue lines that contain strings separating each cell.

How would I be able to create these? Thank you.

[image: Things (C) CulturedCode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the "Section Header Views". You can provide them by implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. Specifically the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To add to @LuisCien's answer, you may need to implement the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol as well.  You will need to provide the number of sections your table will hold.  Here are some methods to consider:

[UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

- `(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`
- `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`

Answer (score 0):

```
Here You can add your customView
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

}
Here you can add your title
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}
here you can define the number of section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
}
```